# Depending on textview's text, changing the static spinner value

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

I am getting successfully previous activity value through intent. The get value store in TextView.

Only work else part of this code. 'If' part not working. I place this code in 'onCreate' method.

I want to do if text view contains "English" spinner should be run "English_array. if "Arabic" should be run "Arabic_array.

I want to work 'if' also depending on Textview's change.

```
 public class TweetDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,
    DialogInterface.OnCancelListener{


Toolbar toolbar;

String[] subject;
String[] stages;
String[] via;
int position;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweet_detail);


TextView Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle); 

if (TitleName.toString().equals("English")){
        Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.English_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        staticAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

    }else if(TitleName.toString().equals("Arabic")){

        Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.Arabic_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        staticAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

   }else {

        Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.Tamil_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        staticAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
    }

// Retrieve data from MainActivity on listview item click
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the listview item click subject
    subject= i.getExtras().getInt("subject");
    // Get the list of stages
    stages = i.getStringArrayExtra("stages");
    // Get the list of via
    via = i.getStringArrayExtra("via");


    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);
    Body = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);
    Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweetDate);

    // Load the text into the TextViews followed by the position
    Title.setText(subject[position]);
    Body.setText(stages[position]);
    Date.setText(via[position]);
 }
 }
```

Title(Transfer the listview value to textview) :

```
 public class MainActivity_Third extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
 ListView list;
TweetAdapter adapter;
String[] subject;
String[] stages;
String[] via;


int i = 0;
View v;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity__third);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_activity__third, container, false);
    i++;

    subject= new String[]{"Arabic","English","Tamil"};

    stages = new String[]{"Certificate" ,"| Diploma ","| Higher Diploma"};

    via= new String[]{"Tamil | Distance Learning, Direct", "Tamil | Distance Learning, Direct",
            "Tamil | Distance Learning, Direct", "Tamil | Distance Learning, Direct"};

    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    adapter = new TweetAdapter(MainActivity_Third.this.getActivity(), rank, country, population);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
 @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity_Third.this.getActivity(), TweetDetailActivity.class);
    // Pass all data subject
    i.putExtra("subject", subject);
    // Pass all data stages
    i.putExtra("stages", stages);
    // Pass all data via
    i.putExtra("via", via);
    // Pass listview item click position
    i.putExtra("position", position);
    // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

My res XML code below:

```
 <string-array name="English_array">
      <item>Certificate in English</item>
      <item>Diploma in English</item>
      <item>Higher Diploma in English</item>
 </string-array>

 <string-array name="Arabic_array">
     <item>Diploma in Arabic</item>
     <item>Higher Diploma in Arabix</item>
 </string-array>

 <string-array name="Tamil_array">
     <item>Diploma in Tamil</item>
     <item>Higher Diploma in Tamil</item>
 </string-array>
```

here is spinner XML :

```
      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/static_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Comment: What is Title name is it TextView? Log the value you got from intent

Comment: No, bro. I get Textview 's text from another activity's listview.

Comment: share all the code in question not just if, we have no context of what you are comparing where is `TitleName` initialized please share

Comment: Ok, bro. I add that also.

Comment: What is TitleName ? where is it initialized ?

Comment: TitleName is a TextView. It's initialized in the **TweetDetailActivity**. According to TextView's change, spinner want to be change!